# Camel difference between route properties and exchange properties

Tags: java, properties, apache-camel

Can someone explain me the differences between the two properties?

```
@Override
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    context = new DefaultCamelContext(new SimpleRegistry());        
    template = context.createProducerTemplate();

    context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {

        public void configure() throws Exception {              
            PropertiesComponent prop = context.getComponent(
                                      "properties", PropertiesComponent.class);
            prop.setLocation("classpath:test.properties");

            from("direct:start")
            .log("Property: ${properties:a}")
            .process(new Processor() {

                @Override
                public void process(Exchange ex) throws Exception {
                    String a = ex.getProperty("a", String.class);
                    LOG.info("Property: " + a);
                }
            })
            ;
        }
    });

    context.getShutdownStrategy().setTimeout(1);
    context.start();
}

@Test
public void testRoute() throws Exception {
    template.sendBody("direct:start", null);
}
```

The properties-file (`test.properties`):

```
a = a
```

Output:

```
2015-09-03 14:38:01,740 | INFO  | route1           | Property: a
2015-09-03 14:38:01,743 | INFO  | CamelTest2       | Property: null
```

The first line is from `.log("${properties:a}")`, so it can be found. However, `String a = ex.getProperty("a", String.class);` cannot. Both are properties and point to the same property, right?
What is the difference, and how can I find the property in the processor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Exchange` is only created upon the reception of the request in the client side. And this means that your Camel Processor will have access to the `Message` only and not the property from external resource.

The Exchange's properties are the Message's meta-information. As per the doc,

> The Exchange also holds meta-data during its entire lifetime stored as
>   properties accessible using the various `getProperty(String)` methods.
>   The `setProperty(String, Object)` is used to store a property. For
>   example you can use this to store security, SLA related data or any
>   other information deemed useful throughout processing.

Comment: And additional - The properties.a refers to the property in the properties file. While exchangeProperty (priviously property which is deprecated) referes to the property of the exchange. http://camel.apache.org/simple.html

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks! But is there a possibility to add the whole property file to the exchange?

Comment: Not exactly sure. But if you are using a Java DSL, you have the most flexibility isn't it? write a method that can load property file using a simple java Properties : Properties properties = ..... and add that property to the exchange. It should be simple :)